# Передача произвольного xml и xsd в качестве параметров WCF-службы

Tags: xml, c#, xsd, wcf

В целом, задача выглядит так. Сервер имеет плагинную архитектуру и должен позволять работать с произвольными структурами данных. Основные методы выглядят примерно так:

- Получить список плагинов
- Получить описание структуры данных выбранного плагина
- Запустить выбранный плагин, передав ему данные нужной ему структуры.

Предполагается, что по структуре данных, полученных с сервера, клиент сгенерирует для пользователя диалог, через который можно вводить данные этой структуры.

Мы думаем в сторону связки xsd-xml в качестве данных. Самый простой вариант, естественно - это гонять данные просто как строки. Но хотелось бы не терять хотя бы тот уровень контроля данных, который есть, т.е. на уровне инфраструктуры WCF проверять, что xsd-описания - это верные xsd-документы, а xml-данные - это хорошо оформленный xml. Какие для этого надо использовать типы в контрактах служб?

Второй момент, связанный с этой же задачей, состоит в том, что, возможно, xsd недостаточно для того чтобы сгенерировать диалог для пользователя. Пока что в нашем продукте используются `PropertyDescriptor`'ы, дополненные нашими расширениями, позволяющими на уровне семантики описывать редакторы для свойств. Такие свойства, помимо атрибутов, предоставляемых компонентной моделью `.NET`, имеют описание источника данных, из которого пользователь может выбрать значение для свойства. Насколько я понимаю, это выходит за рамки задачи описания структуры данных, и языка, предназначенного для её решения, может не хватить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, всё сделано. Вот [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa347876.aspx) описана поддержка поддержка нужной возможности WCF.

Решение такое: `xsd` передаётся как набор экземпляров `XmlSchema`, обёрнутый классом, реализующим `IXmlSerializable`, который делегирует реализацию стандартному сериализатору для `List<XmlSchema>`. Файлы с параметрами плагинов на клиенте валидируются по скачанным с сервера xml-схемам, потом передаются на сервер как `XmlElement`. Для работы с диалогами используется другой набор DTO, никак не завязанный на технологию xsd.

Answer (score 0):

На первом этапе вы можете залить xml&xsd во временное хранилище которое будет доступно серверу (FTP например).
На втором этапе вызвать определенный метод WCF который проведет валидацию данных файлов и вернет результат валидации.
Дата контракт которий будет описивать результати валидации может виглядет (в самом простом варианте) примерно так:

```
public class ValidationResults
{
   public List<string> Errors;
   ...
   ...
}
```

Для построение форм можно использовать XSLT.